# can I change my android to ubuntu

Tags: boot

I would like to ask something. Is it possible to change my android phone to ubuntu???
like to change the rom or anythink it needs to be full ubuntu. 
I have galaxy s4 gt-i9505.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is available for only Nexus smart phones. That too only for developer purpose. I don't think there is any custom rom available as of now for other devices.